# RESTful services design - singleton services?

Tags: c#, rest

I have earlier developed an application that exposes a set of RESTful services. I have designed business logic implementation classes and corresponding repository classes completely stateless and they get instantiated every time there is client request. Now I am developing another application with few RESTful services. In this case, one of the services gets data from some other external service and needs to cache that data for some amount of time. I am thinking to cache that data in my application DB and provide it for each request by creating a new business class object. But here I have a doubt - is this correct design? Should I make the business logic class singleton and maintain state (i.e., cache data in memory)?

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have to cache this info `for a certain time` in the first place?

Comment: @Sebas: we don't want to call the external service frequently because we know it takes time to generate that data and our clients need that info very frequently. BTW, if you down voted this, can you please tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some literature study, I conclude that there is nothing wrong in having singleton classes. RESTful services are just resource interfaces for external world but how they will be managed is completely internal. Also I realized there is no need to have end-to-end mappings from data transfer objects (that take requests and send responses) to database columns. My DTOs, in many cases, map to model objects which map to DB tables but I have also designed those three items differently.

Answer (score 0):

I would use web server level caching instead. In asp.net you can use the Cache object, either backed by memory or an external cache provider of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am going to host this service as a Windows Service using OWIN and I am completely new to ASP.Net (and its related Cache object). So, I am not sure if I can use Cache facility from ASP.Net, but I will check. While checking for that I came across https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache/ . It looks promising but my problem is I need to cache some portion of response but not the entire response. Any pointers for this?